# Passing multiple parameters to GET in AngularJS (Ionic)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm having an issue passing parameters to an http.get function. The following snippet works:

```
data.getAPIData = function() {

    return $http.get(apiUrl + "I_RetrieveUserData2", { params: { "currentUserId": "0981ac72-59be-40fc-bb0b-1bf035895b6b", "userId": "0981ac72-59be-40fc-bb0b-1bf035895b6b" } })
      .success(function(data) {

        console.log(data);
        $timeout(function () {
          return data;
        }, 2000);
      })
      .error(function(data) {

        console.log("ERROR");
        $timeout(function () {
          return data;
        }, 2000);
      });
  }
```

Whereas the following does NOT work:

```
data.getAPIData = function(currentUserId, userId) {

    return $http.get(apiUrl + "I_RetrieveUserData2", { params: { "currentUserId": currentUserId, "userId": userId } })
      .success(function(data) {

        console.log(data);
        $timeout(function () {
          return data;
        }, 2000);
      })
      .error(function(data) {

        console.log("ERROR");
        $timeout(function () {
          return data;
        }, 2000);
      });
  }
```

What am I missing? The response I receive is 'userId' parameter is missing.

Comment: Sounds like you are `userId` argument is null/undefined when you pass it into the function. Do you see `userId` in the GET request's querystring?

Comment: Oh man, my colleague and I only just noticed - we're calling it in 2 locations and only logged one output and the one we were logging had the right param values and other other didn't - cheers!

Comment: Also please don't shadow variables from outer scope, as it will cause unexpected behavior. In you case you are using `data` as the name of your object exposing the method as well as the callback parameters for `success` and `error`

Comment: Ah, thanks Aditya - I'll make the change.